# SheetJS Change Header names to dynamic

Tags: sheetjs

I am trying to change the header names in sheetJS to something I recieve from the form. Here is my form submit function:

```
onFormSubmit() {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    const solution = 'testsolution'; // normally i get this from a form input
    fileReader.onload = (e) => {
      this.arrayBuffer = fileReader.result;
      const data = new Uint8Array(this.arrayBuffer);
      const arr = [];
      for (let i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
      const bstr = arr.join('');
      const workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, {type: 'binary'});
      const first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
      const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];
      // change the column names to match entity


      const records = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, {raw: true});
      console.log('records - ', records);
    };
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.file);
  }
```

currently for example my headers come in like this:
AltId, FirstName, LastName
And I want them to end up like this with 'testsolution' apended with underscore and lowercase

testsolution_altid, testsolution_firstname, testsolution_lastname

NOTE: Header names may change depending on what sheet is uploaded. For example the next sheet uploaded may contain headers:

AltId, Address1, Address2, City, State

And should end up like
testsolution_altid, testsolution_address1, testsolution_address2, testsolution_city, testsolution_state

Any help would be appriciated!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it like this if it helps anyone else:

```
 // change the column names to match entity
      const newHeaders = [];
      const columnCount = XLSX.utils.decode_range(ws['!ref']).e.c +1;
      console.log(columnCount);
      for (let i = 0; i < columnCount; ++i) {
        newHeaders[i] = solution+'_'+ ws[`${XLSX.utils.encode_col(i)}1`].v.toLowerCase();
        // console.log(header[i]);
      }
      // console.log(newHeaders);
```